# Using ifstream for all .txt files in directory

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am wondering how to read in all files in a directory (.txt) one by one without knowing their file names?

I am familiar with the following simple case and its derivatives:

```
ifstream inTestData;
string inputFile("filename.txt");

inTestData.open(inputFile.c_str());
```

but I wasn't sure if you didn't know the file name and you had multiple files in the directory, of which you want to read all of them (assuming you put all of the .txt's in that directory).

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Standard C++ libraries do not yet include support for traversing
directories, which is what you need to do. You must use the
appropriate APIs of your operating system, having included the
appropriate system headers in your C++ program (or, with less instructive value, use a 3rd party library). So the answer
you want depends on whether you are running on Windows, Linux/Unix or something else. Tell us which and I can probably give you an answer.

Comment: You should look at [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem) for a portable file system library. And also you don't have to pass a c-string to `ifstream::open`, you can pass the string as it is.